# can i make a python variable out of SQLite3 columns

Tags: python, sql

I've looked everywhere and just cant find what im looking for. Here is the psuedocode version of what i want to do:

i want to make the username a variable i can compare to an inputted one in the script and the same with the password

```
getusername = sql.database.column(USERNAME)
getpassword = sql.database.column(PASSWORD)
if getusername == given username:
   login()
```

Comment: You want to use the column name as the username?

Comment: This looks like an [X Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please tell us what you really trying to do.

Comment: i want to make the username a variable i can compare to an inputted one in the script and the same with the password

Comment: it is for a basic authorization system

Comment: When the user has given their username and password you should run a select query (that's what the database is for) with username in `where` condition, get the (hopefully hashed) password from the query and compare that to the given password (or hash thereof)

Comment: Thanks you for this